# Unknown type name 'NSString' when I define a block

Tags: ios, objective-c, block, typedef

When I define my block in my .h file, there comes an issue:

> Unknown type name `NSString`

My code is below:

```
typedef void(^CancelBlock)();
typedef void(^ConfirmBlck)(NSString *); // this line comes the error


#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface LMLUpspringView : UIView

@property (nonatomic, copy) CancelBlock cancelBlock;
@property (nonatomic, copy) ConfirmBlck confirmBlock;


@end
```

But, why is my first block ok and the second report's an error?

Answer (score 3):

You define block above the `#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>` (in the .h file), so there did not import the NSString, you should cut the `#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>` above the block define.

Answer (score 2):

you need to declare block as below

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

    typedef void(^ConfirmBlck)(NSString * string);
```

Comment: You don't need to import Foundation if you're importing UIKit

Answer (score 0):

In latest versions of xcode you can simply specify

```
#import <Foundation/NSString.h>
```

any NS Foundation class can be imported as needed.

Answer (score -1):

position declaration  uikit import then follow:

```
// declare
@property(nonatomic,strong)void(^ConfirmBlck)(NSString * string); 

// define
[self setConfirmBlck:^(NSString *indexpVal) { }];

// call 
if (self.ConfirmBlck) {
    self.ConfirmBlck(selectedVal);
}
```